# Remember me is not working FosBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, remember-me

I followed some tutorials in the web about how to configure remember me option [FOSBundle ]when the users login but it seems nothing is working for me:

```
main:

            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                provider: fos_userbundle
                post_only: true
                use_forward: false
                remember_me:  true
                username_parameter:             email
                password_parameter:             password
                failure_path:                   null
                failure_forward:                false
                target_path_parameter: redirect_url
                default_target_path: /index
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /blog
            remember_me:
                key:    %secret% 
                always_remember_me: true
                remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
                lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
                path:     /
                domain:   ~
```

Comment: There is a bug with version 2.3 of symfony.
Here are the details: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1221

Comment: I solved my problem.
It was rather stupid, in access control I had selected the role IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY ..

access_control:
        - { path: ^/[^/]+/admin, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
For this reason it did not work!